# Emacs25 Empty Menus

Tags: 16.04, emacs

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and Emacs 25.1.2, which I installed from here:

https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs

According to:

[Emacs toolbar icons missing in Ubuntu-16.10, struggle to compile emacs24 and 25](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836690/emacs-toolbar-icons-missing-in-ubuntu-16-10-struggle-to-compile-emacs24-and-25)

the kellyk build should resolve the empty menu problem, but I still get some empty menus, for example when I open a .tex file, the Latex menu is just a grey rectangle if I click on the menu. The menu only becomes populated when I hit F10, but I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix it so that I can click on it.

Answer (score 6):

Rough answer:

I assume that you are using Unity. I haven't tested this, but I think that

```
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-gtk-module blacklist "['emacs25']"
```

should partially solve the issue — your compiled emacs will no longer use the Global Menu, but its own menu, which should be better-behaved. If needed, you can have a longer list of elements in the blacklist — e.g. `"['emacs25', 'emacs26']"`. Restart Emacs after executing the above command!

(Possibly first run:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.unity-gtk-module blacklist
```

to ensure that the list is empty to begin with, and you're not clobbering anything.)

Brief explanation:

`emacs24` from the default repositories has a hardcoded blacklist, but this does not carry over to `emacs25`.

Note: you might need to use the utility `xprop` (e.g. with `xprop WM_CLASS` — you need the first of the displayed strings) to determine the "WM_CLASS" of your emacs window and use that instead of emacs25.

Comment: I tried this, still doesn't work.

Comment: @bkmoney Did you restart emacs after doing this? Just checking :)

Comment: This problem still exists in 17.10. @aplaice's answer works as described after restarting emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to `~/.emacs.d/init.el` worked for me on Emacs 28.0.50 / Ubuntu 18.04:

```
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(menu-bar-mode 1)
```